# Mongoose Schema Validate for Async request

Tags: mongoose, mongoose-schema

I am trying to write validation function to check unique value for email.

**Code 1**

```
userSchema.path('email').validate(function (email, fn) {
    const User = mongoose.model('User');
    if (this.isNew || this.isModified('email')) {
      User.find({ email: email }).exec(function (err, users) {
        fn(!err && users.length === 0);
      });
    } else fn(true);
  }, 'Email already exists');
```

> I am getting an error message **TypeError: fn is not a function**

**Code 2**

```
var emailValidators = [
    {validator:uniqueEmailValidator, message:"Email is registered with us"},
    {validator:emailRegexValidator, message:"Email is not in valid format"}
];



function uniqueEmailValidator(value){
  return this.model('User').count({email:value}, function(err, count){
        if(err || count){
            console.log(count); // I can see this console
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    });
}
```

> No errors here. But validation is missing out and the record is trying to insert.

I am new to mongoose. So please be little explanatory on the answer.

Comment: Why not use a [unique key](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html) constraint? ([mongo docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/index-unique/))

Comment: It didnt workout and while googling i read in stackoverflow that this approach is preferrable as unique will set an index property. Though i am not sure, what it meant, i tried this one and got the code working

Comment: I don't know why using a validator is preferable for a few reasons, primarily that the unique key constraint (it is a special type of index) will always prevent a a duplicate entry while using a validator would not due to race conditions (e.g. concurrent creation and/or updates that would result in the same email address being stored for different records).

Answer (score 1):

I got the answer. I need to add isAsync:true and so i will get the callback function in my validator

```
var emailValidators = [
    {isAsync: true, validator:uniqueEmailValidator, message:"Email is registered with us"},
    {validator:emailRegexValidator, message:"Email is not in valid format"}
]

function uniqueEmailValidator(value, cb){

  return this.model('User').count({email:value}, function(err, count){
        if(err || count){
            return cb(false);
        }
        return cb(true);
    });
}
```